# how to add DB contents into stack then into combobox in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox, stack

I am trying to get the test results from the database. Then I would like to insert these values into a stack. Then I would like to insert the stack into a combobox. So that the top of the stack will be the first value that will be shown in the combobox. The combobox should display all values within the stack.

I tried to do this but I get the wrong output. When I click on the comobox it says

> systems.generic.... (collections)

C# code:

```
private void Results_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=project;username=root;password=***;"))
{
try
{
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT test.test_results FROM test WHERE test.StudentID ='" + student + "';");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MySqlDataReader DBReader;
DBReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (DBReader.Read())
{

    string testResults = DBReader.GetInt32("test_results").ToString();

    Stack<string> results = new Stack<string>();

    results.Push(testResults);

    comboBox1.Items.Add(results.ToString());

}

}

catch (Exception ex)

{

MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

}

connection.Close();

}
```

QUESTIONS:

How can I meet my objective? is there a more efficient way of using the stack? is there a better data structure that I should use that would be better for this task?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The formatting of your code makes it very hard to read on StackOverflow. Please take the time to properly indent the code (by adding 4 spaces to each and every line of code) and maybe break lines to make your intentions clear.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Does that help?

Comment: It looks rather worse than better. Four spaces at the beginning of a line will indicate to the StackOverflow parser that it should render the line in a code box. After that you should *add* the amount of spaces it takes to *properly* read your code as it reads in your IDE. The current version has almost all structure removed. I prefer not to edit your code myself, since I am not at all an expert in C#.